# R two tables merge and create new column for repeat values

Tags: r

Goodday everyone, I am trying to merge two dataframes and create new dataframe that contains the unique columns, and create new columns for repeat values.
For example, two dataframes are:

df1

```
col1 col2
A    B
C    D
```

df2

```
col1 col2 col3
A    B    E
A    B    F
C    D    G
C    D    H
C    D    I
```

Target output is

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
A    B    E    F
C    D    G    H    I
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure weather the final format you are after is something that is helpful. However the first step is a simple left or full join

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "C"),
                  col2 = c("B", "D"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "A", "C", "C", "C"),
                  col2 = c("B", "B", "D", "D", "D"),
                  col3 = c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyverse)

res <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("col1", "col2"))
res

  col1 col2 col3
1    A    B    E
2    A    B    F
3    C    D    G
4    C    D    H
5    C    D    I
```

to get a result in the desired form is a bit trickier.
First we do the same left join as above, we then unite the two columns (`col1` & `col2`) together so that we can group and spread by those columns easily.

Grouping by the united column (`fuse`) we want a number associated with each `col3` value within the group, we paste `"col"` as a prefix so that when spreading it appears as a column name.

We then spread by the counter column `n` and fill it with the values of `col3`.

Finally, we reverse the unite we did earlier.

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("col1", "col2")) %>%
  unite(fuse, col1, col2) %>%
  group_by(fuse) %>%
  mutate(n = paste0("col", 2 + 1:n())) %>%
  spread(n, col3) %>%
  separate(fuse, c("col1", "col2"))


# A tibble: 2 x 5
  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     B     E     F     NA   
2 C     D     G     H     I
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!